# representation of web page as browser see it

Tags: html, dom, web-crawler, representation

I have some ideas of how to build a more intelligent web spider, which interacts with a web page and extracts information in a manner more similar to how us humans do.

To do this I need a representation of a web page that is similar or identical to that we see in our browsers

In other words I need access to the data concerning the location, colour and style of all the elements on the page, possibly at a pixel level.

But I don't want just a rendered bitmap, I want to be able to extract text, click links and push buttons and so on

I get the feeling the DOM model may be a starting point but more concrete advice would be appreciated

**To clarify, I want to programmatically obtain access to web pages in a form similar to that presented to us by a browser, but for example to check the colour or text at a specific pixel location or region.**

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) (or other ways of scripting your browser, such as greasemonkey). Since how a web page is displayed depends quite a bit on the particular browser, scripting one is obviously the most precise way of getting to what the user sees.

Comment: Thanks, but my major concern is getting access to such data in a way that I can manipulate and interact with it programmatically, say through a C++ program.  Discrepancies between browser renderings isn't so much much of an issue.

Comment: With greasemonkey, you can access it programmatically. :-) For C++, you're probably best off using WebKit or an IE ActiveX control or whatever the standard way on your platform of choice is to embed a web browser in your application.